# Show that $1-(-1)^n +1/n$ is divergent.

Tags: real-analysis

> My process was to take each of the two sequences and say that we know $(-1)^n$ is divergent because its two sub-sequences have different limits, and $\frac{1}{n}$ is convergent because it converges to 0. Therefore, because adding a convergent sequence to a divergent sequence is still divergent, $1-(-1)^n +\frac{1}{n}$ must be divergent.

Comment: your reasoning seems correct, you just need to formalize what you are saying to make sure it is.

Comment: so hw would i do that .that is my main problem ? any hint ?@MatthewLevy

Comment: If $a_n$ convergent $b_n$ divergent then $c_n=a_n+b_n$ divergent, because if $c_n$ convergent then $c_n-a_n=b_n$ convergent, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Your reasoning is correct, but perhaps you are expected to give an "$\epsilon$-$N$" proof, in which case much more needs to be done. In a real analysis course, my guess is that you are supposed to show that there is no $L$ which is the limit. I would pick say $\epsilon=1/2$, and show there is no $L$ and $N$ such that if $n\gt N$ then $|a_n-L|\lt \epsilon$.